# How many way can we assign 4 boys and 4 girls to 6 tables that has 2 chairs with some extra rules?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Hi I've got a permutation problem and I wonder if there is some neat solution to it instead of my brute force method?

I've tried to simplify my problem to make it as easy as possible to interpret and understand.

---

### Problem

Suppose we have **4 boys** which I call $X$ and **4 girls** which I call $Y$. The boys and the girls are in a classroom that has **6 tables**, each table has **2 chairs**, so there is a total of **12 chairs**.

**The rules are the following**: **2** of the *boys* **must** share a table with **2** of the *girls*. **NO boy** is allowed to share a table with another boy and **NO girl** is allowed to share a table with another girl.

How many ways can we assign the boys and the girls to the chairs so that the rules stated above are fulfilled? I will denote a table with two chairs as "(..)"

I.e. we begin with the setup

$(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)$

Suppose we decide to seat one of the girls first. There are 12 different chairs we could assign the first girl to

$12(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(.Y)$

The second girl can be assigned to 10 different chairs since we don't allow any (YY) combinations. So

$12\cdot10(..)(..) (..) (..) (.Y) (.Y)$

After we have seated all the girls we have

$12\cdot10\cdot8\cdot6(..)(..) (.Y) (.Y) (.Y) (.Y)$

Now when we are going to assign the first boy to one of the empty chairs. We can either assign him to a table that's empty or we can let him share a table with a girl.

$12\cdot10\cdot8\cdot6\cdot4[(..)(.X) (.Y) (.Y) (.Y) (.Y)+(..)(..) (XY) (.Y) (.Y) (.Y)]$

Assigning the second boy to a chair we have the following combinations

$12\cdot10\cdot8\cdot6\cdot4
[2(.X)(.X) (.Y) (.Y) (.Y) (.Y)
+8(..)(.X) (XY) (.Y) (.Y) (.Y)
+3(..)(..) (XY) (XY) (.Y) (.Y)]$

Now **remember** that we do not allow more than **two** $(XY)$ combinations!
Thus for the third boy we get

$12\cdot10\cdot8\cdot6\cdot4
[24(.X)(.X) (XY) (.Y) (.Y) (.Y)
+36(..)(.X) (XY) (XY) (.Y) (.Y)]$

And finally for the last boy we get

$12\cdot10\cdot8\cdot6\cdot4
[72(.X)(.X) (XY) (XY) (.Y) (.Y)
+72(.X)(.X) (XY) (XY) (.Y) (.Y)]$

Which can be simplified to

$72\cdot12\cdot10\cdot8\cdot6\cdot4\cdot2
(.X)(.X) (XY) (XY) (.Y) (.Y)$

So $72\cdot12\cdot10\cdot8\cdot6\cdot4\cdot2$ give us 
a total of $3317760$ **number of ways** to assign the boys and the girls to the chairs!

---

**My question:**
My solution is not that pretty, it just pure brute force. Is there a better and more elegant way to encode the solution to the problem instead of my brute force method?

**EDIT1:** The children and the tables and the chairs are distinguishable.

**EDIT2:** You are allowed to change the order of the chairs within a table so that for example $(YX)=(XY)$

Comment: Are the tables distinguishable?  Are the chairs at a table distinguishable? Are the boys distinguishable? Are the girls distinguishable?

Comment: Are the children distinguishable?

Comment: @Bram28 The boys/girls, chairs and tables are all indistinguishable.

Comment: @Dror The boys are indistinguishable from the boys and the girls are indistinguishable from the girls.

Comment: @Turbotanten Well, then your calculations seem to immediately have a problem, since right at the start you say that the first girl can be seated in one of 12 chairs ... but if all tables are chairs are indistinguishable, then sitting the first person in whichever chair is all the same. Indeed, if ther tables and chairs are all indistinguishable, then as far as sitting the girls go, there is only $1$ possibility: have them sit at different tables!

Comment: Thanks :). I say relax it by sitting 2 mandatory couples. That's $1$. Then you have 4 tables, 4 children, 2 of each flavor. If you don't distinguish anything from anything other than the gender, disregard it to, calculate simply by how many kids are standing. then break the rules and put only boys with boys, and only girls with girls (or sitting alone), subtract.

Comment: @Bram28 Sorry, then I ment that the chairs and tables are distinguishable but the children are indistinguishable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the tables, chairs, boys, and girls are all indistinguishable, and if the rule:

> **2** of the *boys* **must** share a table with **2** of the *girls*.

is interpreted (as you do) as there being *exactly* $2$ tables with a boy and a girl (as opposed to there being *at least* $2$ tables with a boy and a girl), then there is *exactly* $1$ possibility here:  have $2$ tables with a boy and a girl, $2$ tables with a boy, and $2$ tables with a girl.

Are you sure that there cannot be more than $2$ tables with a boy and a girl?

EDIT

If the tables are distinguishable, and the chairs are, but the boys are not, and girls are not, you are still overcounting: For example, sitting the first girl at table $1$, chair $a$, and the second girl at table $2$, chair $a$, is the same thing as putting the first girl at table $2$, chair $a$, and the second at table $1$, chair $a$.... exactly because the girls are indistinguishable.

Similarly, you are overcounting the number of ways we can sit down the boys because you make a difference between putting the first boy at a table with a girl, and the second one not, and vice versa, but if the boys are indistinguishable, those two actions amount to the same thing.

So, for the girls you just need to pick the $4$ tables out of $6$ where the girls are going to sit, and multiply by $2^4$ since the chairs are distinguishable. So that's ${6 \choose 4} = 15$ times $16$ is $240$ possibilities.

For the boys: first you need to create two tables with a boy and a girl ... i.e. pick $2$ out of the $4$ tables with a girl: that's ${4 \choose 2} = 6$ possibilities. Then, for the last two boys the last two tables are determined, but they do have a choice of $2$ chairs each, so that's another factor of $4$

So, you have a total of $240 \cdot 6 \cdot 4= 5760$ possibilities.

Comment: Can't the children refuse to sit?

Comment: @Dror Heehee, thinking outside the box :)

Comment: @Dror No the children can't refuse to sit xD

Comment: @Bram28 There cannot be more nor less than 2 tables with a boy and a girl

Comment: So how did you get 3 million! :):)

Comment: @Bram28 A nice challenge would be having the boys with boson statistics and the girls fermions in nature

Comment: @Bram28 Sorry for the confusion. Then I totally ment that the boys and girls are distinguishable as well.

Comment: @turbotanten ok, then muliply my answer by $4!$ to distinguish the girls, and another $4!$ for the boys... does that equal your answer?